# How to run a long shell script code in a java program?

Tags: java, shell

I'm writing a Java program that should ssh to an IP and run a shell script code.

The problem is the script is too long and should be carry by the java code.

I used sshxcute library.

I have two solutions:

1. putting all scripts line by line to JAVA code as an string and execute them at once.(how to do that?) or separate that script code to 80 lines as strings and run them in JAVA one by one.(I don't think this is an efficient way! but the only way I know how to do that)
2. Put that shell script code in JAVA file and execute it by JAVA (I don't know how to do that.). where should I put it (main package?) and who to address to that?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to start the ssh session on the remote machine, and then pipe commands to it:

```
// start ssh session to machine alan
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("ssh", "alan").start();
// get a means of reading its output
final Scanner reader = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
// start a new thread going to read its output
Thread readThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (reader.hasNextLine())
            System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
        reader.close();             
    }
});
readThread.start();
// get a means of sending it commands
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
// send some commands
writer.println("touch /tmp/somefile");
writer.println("hostname");
writer.println("ls -l /home");
writer.println("uptime");
writer.println("exit");
writer.close();
// wait for reading thread to finish
readThread.join();
```

That starts the process up, and logs into the remote machine. Then it starts a new thread going to read the output from the process (which is an *input stream* as far as your program's concerned), and creates a `PrintWriter` that you can use to send commands (which is the process's input, but an *output stream* as far as your program's concerned).

When I run this on my laptop, I get

```
alan
total 20
drwx------ 65 james james  4096 Oct 16 21:50 james
drwx------  2 root  root  16384 Apr  1  2014 lost+found
 23:12:13 up 6 days,  8:46,  5 users,  load average: 0.19, 0.19, 0.20
```

which, as you can see, is the output of the commands I sent.

Comment: is this code for run in Linux machine? What about if I want to run these bash script on another machine that connected to Linux machine by specific Ip and password?

Comment: @HoKa it's connecting to a machine via ssh, and then sending some commands. The commands I gave in my code were just examples. The Java is not platform specific, but if you're sending commands to a machine via ssh then the commands you send will have to be appropriate for that machine, whatever it's running. But it's the ssh server's operating system that determines what type of command to send, not the machine on which you're running your Java application.